# Asp.net MVC- Unable to see checkbox boxes when using CheckBoxListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I am trying to use checkboxlistfor in mvc to generate checkboxes dynamically for my items.Below is my View code for checkboxlistfor:

```
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
<td>
<label>Searchfor</label>
</td>
<td>
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.PostedSearchableObject.PostedIds,
model => model.AvailableObjectTypes,
objecttype => objecttype.Id,
objecttype => objecttype.Name,
model => model.SelectedObjectTypes,
Position.Horizontal) </td>
```

When I run the solution I can see all the items that I need to have a checkbox for (ex: item1, item2, item3), but the problem is there are no Check-boxes next to each item for the user to select them. they are just a simple labels without a check box.

Does anyone has any idea why I can't see the check-boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing all the code? Do you have the plugin downloaded?